# Flex set function not getting called

Tags: apache-flex

Okay, I've been banging my head against the wall with this one. I have the following set function in Flex.

```
    public function set periodChangeAmount(value:int):void
    {
        _PeriodChangeAmount = value;
        refreshStartEndDates();
    }
```

If I set the periodChangeAmount to -1 or 1 the set method gets fired. If I set it to zero it doesn't get fired. What's the deal? Does anyone know why it wouldn't get called when setting it to zero. If I change the object type to a number or even an object it still doesn't work as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This works fine for me.  Can you provide the code you are using to test this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you put a trace in the setter to make sure it isn't called?

Is `periodChangeAmount` a `Bindable` read-write property? In that case flex internally calls the getter to make sure that the value to be set is not the existing value. If the current value of the property (as returned by the getter) is same as the value to be set, the setter is not called.

```
private var privateVar:Boolean = false;

[Bindable]
public function set readWriteProp(value:Boolean):void
{
    trace("set called with " + value + " current is " + privateVar);
    privateVar = value;
}
public function get readWriteProp():Boolean
{
    trace("get called : " + privateVar);
    return privateVar;
}
//...
a.readWriteProp = true;
a.readWriteProp = true;
```

Traced output:

> get called : false
>   set called with true current is false
>   get called : true

Note that the getter was called twice but the setter was called only once. In the second assignment, since the current value and value to be set are same (true), the setter is not called.

I believe flex dev team did it this way to avoid redundancy in binding.

Comment: Bummer. Is there any way around this if I need to leave the object as Bindable?

Comment: check for the value of periodChangeAmount before calling the setter and call refreshStartEndDates() explicitly if it is the same value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve above problem you can add an bindable Event and dispatch that event before setting any properties as shown below.

```
private var privateVar:Boolean = false; 
[Bindable( "bindableEventProperty" )] 

public function set readWriteProp(value:Boolean):void
{     
    trace("set called with " + value + " current is " + privateVar);  
    privateVar = value; 
}
public function get readWriteProp():Boolean 
{  
    trace("get called : " + privateVar);    
    return privateVar;
}

dispatchEvent( new Event( "bindableEventProperty" ));
a.readWriteProp = true;
a.readWriteProp = true;
```

This event make sure that set method of the property is called even though property value is same.